# clustering/grouping names with little or no anomalies into clusters in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with names field as:

```
print(df)
                              names
   --------------------------------
0  U.S.A.
1  United States of America
2  USA
4  US America
5  Kenyan Footbal League
6  Kenyan Football League
7  Kenya Football League Assoc.
8  Kenya Footbal League Association
9  Tata Motors
10 Tat Motor
11 Tata Motors Ltd.
12 Tata Motor Limited
13 REL
14 Reliance Limited
15 Reliance Co.
```

Now I want to club all these similar kind of names into one category such that the final dataframe looks something like this:

```
print(df)
                              names   group_name
   ---------------------------------------------
0  U.S.A.                             USA
1  United States of America           USA
2  USA                                USA
4  US America                         USA
5  Kenyan Footbal League              Kenya Football League
6  Kenyan Football League             Kenya Football League
7  Kenya Football League Assoc.       Kenya Football League
8  Kenya Footbal League Association   Kenya Football League
9  Tata Motors                        Tata Motors
10 Tat Motor                          Tata Motors
11 Tata Motors Ltd.                   Tata Motors
12 Tata Motor Limited                 Tata Motors
13 REL                                Reliance
14 Reliance Limited.                  Reliance
15 Reliance Co.                       Reliance
```

Now this is just 16 records, so its easy to look up all the possible names and anomalies in their names, and create a dictionary for mapping. But in actual I have a data-frame with about 5800 unique names (NOTE: 'USA' and 'U.S.A.' are counted as different entities when stating the count of unique).
 So is there any programmatic approach to tackle such a scenario?

I tried running fuzzy match using `difflib` and `fuzzywuzzy` libraries but even its final results are not concrete. Often times `difflib` would just match up based on words like 'limited','association',etc. even though they would be referring to two different names with just 'association' or 'limited' as the common word among them.
Any help is appreciated.

**EDIT:**
Even if I create a list of Stop-words with words like 'associatio','limited','cooprations','group',etc there are chances of missing out these stop word names when mentioned differently. For instance, if 'association' and 'limited' are just mentioned as 'assoc.','ltd' and 'ltd.' there are chances that I'll miss out adding some of these to the stop-word list.

I have already tried, topic modelling with LDA and NMF the results were pretty similar to what I had achieved earlier using `difflib` and `fuzzywuzzy` libraries. And yes I did all the preprocessing (converting to lower cases, leamtization, extra whitespaces handling) before any of these approaches

Comment: I think "little or no anomalies" is too vague for us to give concrete help. This is exactly what `fuzzywuzzy` does, but if even `fuzzywuzzy` didn't give satisfying results for you, you need to define your own algorithm to discriminate the strings based on your requirements, which we don't know.

Comment: You could try using some topic modeling techniques such as LDA, although extracting meaningful names for each group will be challenging, you could look into NLTK and try lemmatizing/simplifying the strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Late answer, focusing on it for a hour, you can use `difflib.SequenceMatcher` and filter the ratio where it is greater than `0.6`, and a big chunk of code as well... also I simply remove the last word of each list, in the `names` column after it is modified, and get the longest word which apparently gets your desired result, and here it is...

```
import difflib
df2 = df.copy()
df2.loc[df2.names.str.contains('America'), 'names'] = 'US'
df2['names'] = df2.names.str.replace('.', '').str.lstrip()
df2.loc[df2.names.str.contains('REL'), 'names'] = 'Reliance'
df['group_name'] = df2.names.apply(lambda x: max(sorted([i.rsplit(None, 1)[0] for i in df2.names.tolist() if difflib.SequenceMatcher(None, x, i).ratio() > 0.6]), key=len))
print(df)
```

Output:

```
                                names             group_name
0                              U.S.A.                    USA
1            United States of America                    USA
2                                 USA                    USA
3                          US America                    USA
4               Kenyan Footbal League  Kenya Football League
5              Kenyan Football League  Kenya Football League
6        Kenya Football League Assoc.  Kenya Football League
7    Kenya Footbal League Association  Kenya Football League
8                         Tata Motors            Tata Motors
9                           Tat Motor            Tata Motors
10                   Tata Motors Ltd.            Tata Motors
11                 Tata Motor Limited            Tata Motors
12                                REL               Reliance
13                   Reliance Limited               Reliance
14                       Reliance Co.               Reliance
```

A code with my best effort.

Comment: I would still have to look up for all these anomaly names like `REL` and have a way of mapping them to something more meaningful like `Reliance` which is a lot of effort. But the sequnceMatcher at 60% score and then correcting just the other names that didn't made it to 60% match, is still a new approach. You just showed me a new approach to try, thanks buddy. This is the reason I love stackoverflow.

Comment: @AmanSingh Sorry but i think you may need a little machine learning here, this is my best, i would say to accept it

Answer (score 0):

So according to my knowledge. I don't thinks so you can have accurate results but you can do some of things which would help you to clean your data

1. First lower the strings using .lower()
2. Strip the strings to remove extra spaces using strip()
3. tokenize the strings
4. Stemming and lemmatization of your data

you should do research on sentence similarity multiple libraries exist in python such as gensim,nltk
https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/tutorial.html
https://spacy.io/
https://www.nltk.org/

Even I created very basic document similarity project you can check this github
https://github.com/tawabshakeel/Document-similarity-NLP-

I hope all these things would help you in solving your problem.